# Text is stretching to a new page rather weirdly

Tags: prawn, ruby-2.0

Not sure if I am missing something but I am wrapping blocks of text around a bounding box. However, when it stretches to a new page, the text continues in the lower middle of the page instead of the top bit.

Not quite sure why and not sure if this is the default behavior of bouncing box since I am specifying x,y coordinates; although I couldn't find such thing in the docs

The code below reflects more or less what I have

```
pdf.bounding_box([absolute_bounds_left, pdf.cursor], width: absolute_bounds_right) do
  pdf.text('Something')
  pdf.text('Something else')
  if something
    pdf.text('Another thing')
    ...
  end
  ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised that if you specify a `height` option, the overflowing text will flow to the next page at [x,y]. So I realised that the if you do not supply a `height`, the only thing different is that it will stretch until the end of the page and then behave exactly the same, start at position [x, y].

I searched a bit more into the docs to validate this and indeed there is an example. Sorry no permalink so you have to search for it: http://prawnpdf.org/manual.pdf -> [text/free_flowing_text.rb]

If you notice there is another method, `span` which solved my free flowing text issue. It also comes with a `position` which amongst the standard `:left`, `:right` and `:center` it takes a numeric value as an offset on the y axis. [See here](https://github.com/prawnpdf/prawn/blob/9bbca196e683af6e5e7749793a4cce2a7bec946f/lib/prawn/document/span.rb#L41)